# CMD Connect to a network starting with the string

Tags: batch-file, network-programming, command-prompt, wifi, ar.drone

I'm writing a batch file that will automatically connect to a drone wireless network and land the drone. I want my program to work universally on all of these drones but the problem is, each of these drones has a different, unique wireless network name. However, they all do start with "ardrone". I know that I can connect to a network through command prompt by using:

```
netsh wlan connect name=wifiname
```

and I have tried:

```
netsh wlan connect name=ardrone*
```

The trouble is, such a command returns the message:

```
There is no profile "ardrone*" assigned to the specified interface.
```

Is there a way (and it can be more complex than the method I was attempting) that I can search through the available networks for one that starts with "ardrone" and connect to it? (Not a password protected network). Thanks.

Comment: Parse the `netsh wlan show profiles` output using [`FOR /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to get desired list of names. Cf.  [`netsh wlan connect`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755301(v=ws.10).aspx#bkmk_wlanConn)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with command line. How would I parse and pass the drone's full wireless network name as a parameter to the netsh wlan connect name=___?. I assumed it would be a variable but after connecting to my home network like this: `netsh wlan connect name=%wifiname%` it directly interprets the name of the variable not its value.

Comment: Assume `netsh wlan show profiles` shows something like `all user profile : ardrone1` then `for /F "tokens=1-3* delims=: " %G in ('netsh wlan show profiles^|find /I "all user profile"') do (netsh wlan connect name="%J")` should work from command line. In a batch script, double all percent signs in `for` loop control variables, e.g use `%%G` and `%%J` instead of  `%G` and `%J`, respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using wlan.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
<name>Wlan</name>
<SSIDConfig>
    <SSID>
        <name>Elkjop Demo</name>
    </SSID>
</SSIDConfig>
<connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
<connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
<MSM>
    <security>
        <authEncryption>
            <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
            <encryption>AES</encryption>
            <useOneX>false</useOneX>
        </authEncryption>
        <sharedKey>
            <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
            <protected>false</protected>
            <keyMaterial>insert wpakey</keyMaterial>
        </sharedKey>
    </security>
</MSM>
```

And inject with batch command `netsh wlan add profile filename=wlan.xml`

Will this help you? I guess it will be the solution for the profile error?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond. Your answer was actually very helpful. Thank you for your time!